# Upgraded SQL Server 2008 to 2008 R2 and server can't be found

Tags: sql-server-2008, localhost, ado

I upgraded SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2. Now the server name `./` which has been used in my connection string for ado.net is not working. I have to explicitly say `localhost` to make it work.

Since I have so many projects with `./` I have to keep using them. What should I do to make `./` work and not use `localhost`?

Comment: The server name for the local server is `.` (just the dot) - not `./`. Does just the single `.` work as the server name in your connection string?

Comment: I can't change the connection string to just using . (dot). It used to work with ./ (dot forward slash). The upgrade caused the problem.